# Google Play Store Error in libgdx Game

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I implement the Google Play Store in my libgdx game with the GameHelper class and the IabHelper class. The Leaderboards work but if I try to purchase a item the Google Play Store says: "Requires authorization, please login with a google account". Before I implement the IabHelper my Game show me the Login with my account, but now I see nothing, but without the login I can't see leaderboards or ?
I hope you can help me why the Google Play Store show me the error

here is the androidlauncher code:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener, ActionResolver, IabInterface {

private GameHelper gameHelper;
IabHelper mHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (gameHelper == null) {
        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
        gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    }
    gameHelper.setup(this);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "{----}"; //here stand my key

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this,base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.d("IAB", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }
            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
            Log.d("IAB", "Billing Success: " + result);
        }
    });

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.useCompass = false;
    config.useWakelock = true;

    initialize(new mygame(this,this), config);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Sign in failed");
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Sign in succeeded");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (mHelper != null) {
        // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
        if (mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            Log.d("IAB", "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
    return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
}

@Override
public void loginGPGS() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }
}

@Override
public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "----", score); //---- is my leaderboardkey
}

@Override
public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
    Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);
}

@Override
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "----"), 100); //---- is my leaderboardkey
    }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
    }
}

@Override
public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
    }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}

@Override
public void buy_100_random_points() {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,one_hundret_random_points,RC_Request,mPurchaseFinishedListener,"HANDLE_PAYLOADS");
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        if ( purchase == null) return;
        Log.d("IAB", "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            //complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
            //setWaitScreen(false);
            return;
        }
//            if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
//                //complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
//                //setWaitScreen(false);
//                return;
//            }

        Log.d("IAB", "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(one_hundret_random_points)) {
            // bought the premium upgrade!
            Log.d("IAB", "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");

            // Do what you want here maybe call your game to do some update
            //
            // Maybe set a flag to indicate that ads shouldn't show anymore


        }
    }
};

}
```

this tutorial help me: [tutorial link](http://pipplo.com/?p=62)

if i click on the purchase button logcat show me this in red:

```
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling:     com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3283)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/finsky/billing/lightpurchase/PurchaseParams
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3283) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams" on path: .
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3283) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 
10-19 06:33:27.980 2350-2361/? E/Parcel:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tell you a few instructions. These you must follow instructions to the letter, ok?.

- You log in the developer console with a google account, ok? Then, go to Settings>Account in your phone and DELETE THIS account, if you don't have any google account more, then, you must create another google account for testing the inapp billing, and add it to the phone in Setting>Account. Remember, repeat, in your phone can't be the google account of the developer console. Use another for testing, you could add the account later when you finish your job.
- To be able to test actual purchase, and do not charge. You have to add the account testing gmail in the developer console here:
  (Settings > Account details)

[image]

You will have to add credit card in the moment when you click to purchase inside your app, but make you sure that you can see the sentence below for do not charge:

[image]

- Is very important that you upload an apk that is signed (NOT A DEBUG VERSION), if you don't know how to do this, please let me know and I could help you.
- Unistall your current apk installed in your phone, go to the Store and download the beta version through the Store, yes you can download the beta version through this, just copy the link (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourpackage.change.this), and confirm the beta version. To be able to see and download the beta version with your testing google account is necessary that you add the testing email account in the beta (or alpha) version page.
  In your "APK" menu in your developer console here, for you can add testing email to see the apk in the store (in the store, only can see the apk, the people listed here no anyone else):

[image]

After you do EACH point LISTED here, if you have any problem let me know.
I hope this be useful for you.

Comment: thank you but you see i ride the purchase problem is done ? i hope. the purchase system is not my problem now, the problem is now the google play game service. it work if i start my game in android studio but if i upload the apk on google play and i download it i become a error

Comment: ok i dont understand it. now it works. the play services and the purchase service. i dont understand google. very big thank you for your help

Comment: @wiifree ok, that sounds great. If you don't mind, please vote up my answers in order to gain more reputation, is only a little reward to keep motivated and keep helping to another people. See you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see in logcat a message like "Problem setting up In-app Billing: "??
What kind of error show in your logcat? Could you post?

Remember to buy an item you have to meet several conditions:

- Your apk must be uploaded to your Google Play Developer Console, it's not necessary you publish your apk openly, you can choose a "beta version", for only you can download.  (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) Make sure that you are using your final (not debug) certificate and private key to sign your application.
- If your app has permission to buy (<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />), in the Android-manifiest.xml, a submenu is unblocked in the panel of your apk in the Google Play Developer Console, which you will have to define the item you want to buy. http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#DefineProducts

When you have done these two steps, and show traces of your logcat, such as:

```
Log.d ("IAB", "Problem setting up In-app Billing:" + result);
```

then I could continue helping you.

And please change this:

```
    if (result.isFailure()) {
        //complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
        //setWaitScreen(false);
        return;
    }
```

for this:

```
    if (result.isFailure()) {
        Log.d ("IAB", "Problem with the purchase:" + result);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: and i test some. if i delete the base64EncodedPublicKey to this String base64EncodedPublicKey = ""; it show me the same error. as if the my game dont connect to my account for the in app products

Comment: but logcat show nothing for this Problem setting up In-app Billing. it dont show this in the log. it show this D/IAB: Billing Success: IabResult: Setup successful. (response: 0:OK)

Comment: it's logically because the authentification window come befor the purchase window come and out of the purchase window logcat can not show this Log.d ("IAB", "Problem with the purchase:" + result);

Comment: @wiifree Are you testing using your developer account?  Google Play does not let you use your developer account for any e-commerce with your own apps.  You probably can't even test the test purchases.

Are you "published" the alpha version and create the premium item in the developer console?

If the problem persist:

Can you try to upload the apk again with a different package name and new app on google play and try to recreate the problem?

Comment: i dont publish the alpha version, i test it with a google tester group. and what you mean with premium item ?

Comment: +@wiifree I mean, you have to upload your apk in your developer console, and then create "in-app product"  [developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html), for testing your apk, you can't use the same gmail account

Comment: ok now it works because i published the app as betaversion but now comes a new error. i download the app and if i start it this error come if i try to sign in with a google account: "the appliaction is incorrectly configureeed. check that the package name and signin certificate match the client ID created in developer console. also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with a listed as a tester account. see logs for more information"

Comment: the error for the purchase is now done but you have a idea for this error ?

Comment: @wiifree hi, yes I was writing another answer here below, :) the in-app billing is a pain the ass, but once you can manage the first one, you feel like Hercules and is pretty awesome